# jax-ws client distributed in a jar

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, rad, websphere-7

We have a jax-ws client we are developing in RAD 8.  We want to make the client available to apps by just passing around this JAR.  So i made a java project, generated the client, and then wrote a little wrapper around it to "pretty it up".

I distributed this to a web app and it works and all is well.  But now I am adding "policy sets" like WS-Transaction on the service and client.  Turns out, simple java projects don't support the right "Project Facets" for web service clients and so i can't do that.  What kind of project will let me set these facets into a jar I can pass around?  I know I can do it within the webapp, but I don't want users to have to know how to run the generation or use the generated client (which is less user friendly).

-What type of project allows web service client jars to get Policy Sets?
-How can I change the type of a project after it already exists?  The project is already in source control and I don't want to have to recreate the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention any specific app server, I'll just answer from a WAS perspective (since that's what I know and what I guess you're using).

For a service client to be configured using Policy Sets and Bindings, the client must be  injected (@WebServiceRef annotation) into some container managed component. This can be a servlet, portlet, EJB, etc. Each application then needs to apply the policy set and binding to their instance of the client. So essentially who ever is using it needs to configure it. You can't just to do it once and everyone shares. Ateast not how you're trying to.

I ran into problem on a project before. My solution was to use an EJB as the container managed component that would have the client instance injected into it. I configure the client once for the EJB component. The EJB then just implements a dumb facade for the service API methods. All the serlvets then just get a reference to the EJB (either via more injection or JNDI lookup) and call the service client through the EJB. It ends up being an extra layer just to make service call but it means we configure the client once for all servlets instead of once for each servlet individually.

Comment: Yes, I am using WAS 7.  @NickRoth, okay, so I can't assign the policy set on the client jar.  But when the webapp with servlets includes the jar, shouldn't I be able to apply the setting there?  My app that uses the jar shows "AppName: null" in the Services view even though it uses this jar to call the service just fine.

Comment: How do you get an instance of your service client class?